# Getting past 30 grift with Rimeheart/LoG

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Has anyone gotten past a lvl 30 grift with a Rimeheart and a Light of Grace ?

[This is what I use currently](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/profile/Imburian-2185/hero/47735596).

I'd like some advice on how to improve gear and generally what stats/gems should I be aiming for.
This char can currently solo 25, but I'm having trouble going past that.

Ideally I'd like for someone to show me a wizard character profile that can solo 30 and above and uses Rimeheart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was interested in a cold build myself awhile ago, but after doing some research on it, it looks like that is the best you are going to do. All the information you need is on this [subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo3Wizards/comments/2i2r1e/frostburns_rimeheart_and_a_cold_build_thoughts/).

Basically with the current gear that is available for cold builds, the gear puts a heavy limit on how many levels in GRs you can do.

From my experience for wizard cold builds you can build a tank/cc build. To do this use Azure Blade instead of rimeheart for the extra freeze chance on every hit along with frostburn gloves. You can almost permanently freeze mobs around you with ice shield.

Comment: I am new here and would like to know why my answer got down voted, Please explain.